# Retrieve date value from database and assign it in to string variable C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the date from my database and stores it in a variable[here is the data from my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Yph.png)

This is my current code but this take time and date

```
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT timeOut_AM FROM TimeOut_AM WHERE FORMAT(timeOut_AM, 'yyyy/MM/dd') = CONVERT (DATE, SYSDATETIME());", conn);

SqlDataReader reader2 = null;

conn.Open();
reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();

while (reader2.Read())
{
    chkDate_AM = Convert.ToString(reader2["timeOut_AM"]);
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also that `WHERE` you have isn't going to be SARGable. Rather than converting your column `timeOut_AM` to an `nvarchar` and then to a `date`, use a date boundary with `>=` and `<` logic; it'll *be far* more efficient.

Comment: This question has got nothing at all to do with databases or ADO.NET. A `DateTime` is a `DateTime`, no matter where it comes from. Call `ToString` on your `DateTime` and specify the format you want. This is something you should have been able to find out with a little research.

Comment: What result do you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
 chkDate_AM = reader2["timeOut_AM"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ;
```

Comment: That won't work as is because indexing a data reader returns an `object` reference, so there's no such overload of `ToString`. The data reader has a `GetDateTime` method, or you can cast the result of the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the DataType of "timeOut_AM" from SQL is DateTime you can do a  convert in the reader. Note you assuming it is a DateTime from SQL and that the value will never be null.

```
chkDate_AM = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["timeOut_AM"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```